# android sdk prompt toast message in account settings

Tags: android, authentication, message, account

I'm using an AbstractAccountAuthenticator and I want to single account for my app. So when the user is opting to add a new account for this app I want to prompt a message. I saw other apps use a toast for the message, but for some reasons mine doesn't get displayed.

I display the message like this:

```
public Bundle addAccount() {
    if (accounts.size() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.MSG_ONLY_ONE_ACCOUNT_IS_SUPPORTED, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why? I'm checking the accounts number in the addAccount() method from AbstractAccountAuthenticator.

Comment: Have you verified that `addAccount()` is being called and that `accounts.size()` is actually `> 0`?

Comment: Yes, everything is ok, except for the message that is not displayed

Answer (score 13):

I've been looking around for the same. The following answers have helped me: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13828857/856202), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186068/856202).

Using your code example:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

public Bundle addAccount(...) {
    if (accounts.size() > 0) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        final String message = 
                  mContext.getString(R.string.MSG_ONLY_ONE_ACCOUNT_IS_SUPPORTED);
        bundle.putInt(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_CODE, 1);
        bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, message);

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return bundle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the Handler is defined outside of the addAccount method otherwise you will get an error (like I did). Just an FYI to everyone.

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. Saved my day.

Comment: Thank you!,  I dont know if this is the best way to display errors in Account Manager, but it works!